# Javafx Nodes only able to be in one Group?

Tags: javafx

I am not sure if this is a bug or not or just my JavaFX program but I am trying to add nodes to several Groups (only one of which is added to the scene) and encountering an oddity where the node will automatically remove itself from the previous group when I add it to another group.

I can't find any documentation on this talking about objects only being able to belong to one group, so was wondering whether its a bug or meant to be? I was hoping to use several groups to collect items in different groupings so that I can apply high level effects such as MouseTransparency, Opacity etc to whole groups on a on/off basis rather than iterate through items as a list where some child objects already have things like MouseTransparency disabled (therefore I don't want to turn it back on for items that originally did not have MouseTransparency - a feature that was handy by adding them to groups).

I note that you can add groups as a child to other groups. I have tried solving my problem by having this, groups nested under the main visually shown Group, but had to abandon that as I could not do a comparator sort on all the wholes if they are contained within sub-groups as I could then only sort either within a sub-group or sort the groups as groups within the main Group, rather than sorting all the nodes across all sub-groups.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that it is an "undocumented side effect" (Edit: apparently it is documented. See jewelsea's answer) of `Group`, as it was not made to do what you're trying to make it do. For some of your stated goals (e.g. opacity) you can use CSS pseudo-classes. For others (like mouse transparency) you can't, but then again - I don't believe this can be conceptually achieved by out-of-scene-graph groups, as it is a strictly UI related...

Comment: In several places in the documentation, e.g. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/package-summary.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) it's stated that "A node may appear at most once in the scene graph".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) documentation:

> If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region, etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from its former parent.